# RavenDB community license limitations

Tags: licensing, ravendb

Is there any technical limit on community version? (cores\memory size\cluster features\etc)
Googled a lot, but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can recall, ravendb's community license only limitation (aside from support) is the inability to use authentication features. 
Everything else is fully unlocked.

For more info read [this](https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.5/csharp/server/configuration/authentication-and-authorization)

Answer (score 0):

Community license for RavenDB 6+ allows 12 static indexes and 24 auto indexes running, only